# Select next occurance of a class after the current selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to change the state of one form field, "idSerialNo" based on changes to another, "idVerification", but I'm having difficulty accessing the correct element, as there are three forms on the page.

The relevant section of each for looks like this:

```
// Input 1, a select element
<div id="sigIDVerification_field" class="clearfix  ">
    <label for="sigIDVerification"> … </label>
    <div class="input">
        <select id="sigIDVerification" class="span5 selectpicker sortable idVerification" name="sigIDVerification" style="display: none;"> … </select>
        <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select span5 sortable idVerification"> … </div>
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
// Input 2, a text input
<div id="sigIDSerialNo_field" class="clearfix  ">
    <label for="sigIDSerialNo"> … </label>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="sigIDSerialNo" class="span5 idSerialNo" type="text" value="" name="sigIDSerialNo"></input>
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the wrapping on the select element is due to a custom skin.

I'm trying to register an event listener for the `select.idVerification` element of each of the three forms. When the select element is changed, I want to check if it is the default value, if so hide the the div block (here `div#sigIDSerialNo_field`) and set the value of `input.idSerialNo` to `""`; if the value of the select element is not default, it will unhide `div#sigIDSerialNo_field`, if it is hidden. My problem is that the id for each of the divs to show/hide will be different, and out of my control.

What I want to do is select the next occurence of `.idSerialNo` after this `.idVerification` and then I can get the grandparent of the `.idSerialNo` element. However, I've found that `.next()` only works on direct siblings, so I can't use that.

Is there a way I can accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to the next `.idSerialNo` in the same form like this:

```
// assume item is jQuery object pointing to your current .idSerialNo
var nextSerialNo = item.closest("div.clearfix").next().find(".idSerialNo");
```

This, finds the grandparent of the current `.idSerialNo`, then finds the very next div in the HTML that's at the same level in the form you are currently in, then finds the `.idSerialNo` object in that div.

This code assumes that the selector `"div.clearfix"` will always identify the proper parent.  If that is not the case, then you have to put a better class consistently on that parent or write more code to find the proper parent object with whatever logic works for all of your HTML.  You don't disclose all the HTML so I can't really identify what pattern would work if `"div.clearfix"` doesn't work everywhere.

The key to this navigation is going up the hierarchy to the right parent, then going `.next()` from there, then using `.find()` in the right parent.

Comment: item would be a jQuery object pointing to the current `.idVerification` and I want to find the next `.idSerialNo` _in the same form_.

Comment: @evanjdooner - I've modified my answer to do what you have asked in your comment.

Comment: That div.clearFix is generated as the top-level parent of each form field block, so it should work every time. I'll try out your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: This solution works. Just a quick note: it's `.clearfix`, not `.clearFix`. That kept me confused for a good ten minutes. :D

Comment: @evanjdooner - fixed the capitalization of `.clearfix` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to check if the selected item is default (I assumed it to be the first element - index 0) and hide the sibling `div.clearfix` of the closest `div.clearfix` class and clear input in the sibling.

Check the **updated** demo. Using `next()` assumes that there are no elements between the `div`s. I changed it to `siblings()` to make sure it will  work even if there are other elements between the `div`s.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhTr/4/)

```
$(function () {
    $("select.idVerification").change(function () {

        var divToHide = $(this).closest("div.clearfix").siblings("div.clearfix");

        if ($(this)[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
            // clear input
            divToHide.find(".idSerialNo").val("");
            // hide
            divToHide.hide();

        } else {
            // show 
            divToHide.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer hides the first block (containing the select element). My goal is to hide the second block (containing the text box) while the select element value is default.

Comment: @evanjdooner see updated answer and demo. changed from `next` to `siblings`

Comment: In this particular case, the divs will be beside each other. I'm not sure if it would affect `siblings()` but there will be other `div.clearfix` elements at the same document level.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided on the following solution, based on the answers of jfriend00 and Lobo:

```
var idVerification = $("select.idVerification");

idVerification.each(function() {
    var nextIDSerialNo_field = $(this).closest("div.clearfix").next();
    nextIDSerialNo_field.addClass('hidden');
    nextIDSerialNo_field.hide(0);
});

idVerification.change(function() {

    var nextIDSerialNo = $(this).closest("div.clearfix").next().find(".idSerialNo");
    var nextIDSerialNo_field = $(this).closest("div.clearfix").next();

    if($(this).val() === "NONE"){
        nextIDSerialNo_field.hide('slow');
        nextIDSerialNo_field.addClass("hidden");
        nextIDSerialNo.val("");
    } else {
        nextIDSerialNo_field.removeClass("hidden");
        nextIDSerialNo_field.show("slow");
    }
});
```